# Delay in taking screenshots

Tags: android, android-asynctask, screenshot

I have an activity in my app where it takes several screen captures and move to next activity on a button click. I want to show some progress or status to the user while taking screenshot(It takes 5-8 seconds). I tries using `AsyncTask` with `runOnUithread()`. But no luck. Even when I wrote the whole code in `doInBackground()`, I don't know why ProgressDialog starts after taking all the screenshots. What is the better way to do this? Here is my code:

```
public class TakeScreenShots extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        private ProgressDialog dialog;


            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                this.dialog = ProgressDialog.show(MyActivity.this, "MyTitle",
                        "Loading .....", true);

            }

            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                 MyActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        takeScreenshots();

                    }
                }); 

                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) {
                gotoNextActivity();

                this.dialog.dismiss();

            }

        }
```

Comment: If you implement asynctask it should display progress dialog and move to next activity once it finishes.

Comment: yeah. but it's not doing like that. Progress dialog appears after takeScreenShots() method is called.

Comment: What are you doing in NExt screen?

Comment: @user370305 its a time taking method. Actually it takes more than 5 secs. So I wanted to show some progress dialog to the user. I guess whats there in that method should not matter. It should happen only in the background with a progress dialog displaying right?

Comment: Nothing just displaying all captured images. @Sameer

Comment: @user370305 ok. now i got it. But, to take screenshots, we need to get drawing cache of an image. So, it needs to be run on Ui thread right?

Comment: @user370305 so any alternate? other than AsyncTask?

Comment: @hotveryspicy It doesn't work in doInBackground

Comment: It's unable to get drawing cache of an ImageView in doInBackground method

Comment: just have takescreenshot in doinbackground. remove all other codes in doinbackground. It should work. No need create a thread again in doInbackground()

Comment: You are displaying image to next screen.So you need to keep dialog in next screen while you load images from Sdcard to screen.

Comment: @user370305 hmm agree, but while capturing screen there is no need of UI manipulation. See I have given an example if you want to change UI do that in `preExecute()`, `doInBackground()` will going to generate only views and bitmap.

Comment: @user370305 again agree with you but this works fine for me, and in `onPostExecute()` I am sending screen via Email.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer from an answer in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7937399/android-view-viewrootcalledfromwrongthreadexception-only-the-original-thread-t). I was setting a drawable to the image view. So, I kept that line on Ui Thread and remaining in doInBackground().

Comment: This I already mentioned in my comments *See I have given an example if you want to change UI do that in `preExecute()`*

Answer (score 1):

No you are doing wrong, instead capturing in `runOnUiThread` Directly capture it in `doInBackground()`

Here is the working example

```
public class backImageProcess extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
    {
private ProgressDialog dialog;
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {

            this.dialog = ProgressDialog.show(MyActivity.this, "MyTitle",
                        "Loading .....", true);

            try {
                File mFile= new File(mTempImagename);
                if(mFile!=null)
                    mFile.delete();
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }   

            super.onPreExecute();
        }
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            mLayoutRoot.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
            mLayoutRoot.buildDrawingCache();

            Bitmap mBitmap= mLayoutRoot.getDrawingCache();
            try {
                if(mBitmap!=null)
                {
                    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(mTempImagename);
                    mBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, out);
                    out.flush();
                    out.close();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) { }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            if(this.dialog!=null)
                this.dialog.dismiss();

            gotoNextActivity();

        }
    }
```

Comment: But my code actually has a for loop that takes many screenshots. I mean Drawables of a ImageView are changed and screenshot is taken. May be some 10 to 15 screenshots.

Comment: I tried keeping my code in doInBackground as you did for taking a single capture. It doesn't work

Comment: It throws this exception: android.view.ViewRoot$CalledFromWrongThreadException

Comment: You must share some of your `takescreen()` code, I cant assume anything now